# How to tune Azure Maps to get the corract location?

Tags: javascript, azure, geolocation, maps, azure-maps

I am interested in Azure Maps' animation library. After setting up an account and initialized the map. I found out that the coordinates I put as parameters aren't the ones it shows.
For Example I currently live in Tunisia. So I've set up the center coordinates to (36.800697, 10.181198).
But, the map gets centered at Addis Ababa for some reason. I am currently following their code example "Animate marker along path". [Github link][1] As you can see I have set up a bunch of mock coordinates.
PS: In the following example, I will mask my key.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Animate marker along path - Azure Maps Web SDK Samples</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="description" content="This sample shows how to easily animate a HTML marker along a path on the map." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Microsoft maps, map, gis, API, SDK, animation, animate, animations, point, symbol, pushpin, marker, pin" />
    <meta name="author" content="Microsoft Azure Maps" />

    <!-- Add references to the Azure Maps Map control JavaScript and CSS files. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2.0/atlas.min.css">
    <script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/javascript/mapcontrol/2/atlas.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add reference to the animation module. -->
    <script src="../Common/scripts/azure-maps-animations.min.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var map, marker, animation;

        //Create an array of points to define a path to animate along.
        var path = [
            [36.80067, 10.19111],
            [36.80081, 10.19077],
            [36.80148, 10.19548],
            [36.83469, 10.30360]
        ];

        function GetMap() {
            //Initialize a map instance.
            map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
                center: [36.817421, 10.305192],
                zoom: 13,
                view: 'Auto',
                
        //Add your Azure Maps key to the map SDK. Get an Azure Maps key at https://azure.com/maps. NOTE: The primary key should be used as the key.
                authOptions: {
                    authType: 'subscriptionKey',
                    subscriptionKey: '<key>'
                }
            });

            //Wait until the map resources are ready.
            map.events.add('ready', function () {
                //Create a data source and add it to the map.
                datasource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
                map.sources.add(datasource);

                //Add a line for the path as a visual reference.
                datasource.add(new atlas.data.LineString(path));
           
                //Add a layer for rendering line data. 
                map.layers.add(new atlas.layer.LineLayer(datasource));

                //Create a marker and add it to the map.
                marker = new atlas.HtmlMarker({
                    position: [-122.33825, 47.53945]
                });
                map.markers.add(marker);

                map.events.add('click', function () {
                    if (animation) {
                        //Restart the animation.
                        animation.reset();
                        animation.play();
                    } else {
                        animation = atlas.animations.moveAlongPath(path, marker, { duration: 2000, captureMetadata: true, autoPlay: true });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="GetMap()">
    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:100%;min-width:290px;height:600px;"></div>

    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:calc(50% - 100px);background-color:white;padding:5px;">Click the map to animate marker.</div>

    <fieldset style="width:calc(100% - 30px);min-width:290px;margin-top:10px;">
        <legend><h1 style="font-size:16px">Animate marker along path</h1></legend>
        This sample shows how to easily animate a HTML marker along a path on the map.
        This sample uses the open source <a href="https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-maps-animations" target="_blank">Azure Maps Animation module</a>
    </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You inverted longitude and latitude. The azure-maps library expects the longitude first :

```
map = new atlas.Map('myMap', {
                center: [10.305192, 36.817421],
                zoom: 13,
                view: 'Auto',
                
        //Add your Azure Maps key to the map SDK. Get an Azure Maps key at https://azure.com/maps. NOTE: The primary key should be used as the key.
                authOptions: {
                    authType: 'subscriptionKey',
                    subscriptionKey: '<key>'
                }
            });
```

Comment: Correct. Azure Maps aligns with geospatial systems which use the format [longitude, latitude]. One of the reasons this is preferred by the geospatial community is that it aligns with [x, y]

Comment: @rbrundritt, where is this "preference" documented? There is a standard, why not follow [ISO 6709](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_6709#Items) ?

Comment: Azure Maps uses EPSG:4326 coordinate reference system, a standard used for WGS84 GPS coordinates. In the geospatial world OGC standards are prefered over ISO standards. If you go through the OGC specifications for most human readable spatial data formats that call out EPSG:4326, nearly all of them specifically say longitude should be before latitude. This is true for the most popular spatial data formats; GeoJSON, KML, Well Known Text. Google's search box introduced lat/lon ordering to the vain of the GIS industry and broke away from widely accepted standard. GIS systems usually align with OGC